# UI5 OData bind multiple entities to sap.m.Table

Tags: xml, odata, sapui5

I am testing a UI5 application using the Northwind Database. I am trying to bring two entities together (`Products` and `Suppliers`). I want to show the supplier for each product in a table.

I have managed to get it to work using `parameters:{expand : 'Supplier'}` in the `items` parameter of the `sap.m.Table`, however, this brings back all data for every field.

So it brings back something similar to the following (where the first two columns are pulled from `/Products` and the last column is pulled from `/Supplier`:

```
ProductName    UnitPrice    SupplierName
Bread          10           Big Bread Co
```

At the moment my path is set to:

```
items="{
    path: '/Products',
    sorter: {
        path: 'ProductName',
        descending: false
    }
}"
```

and I have tried to access the Supplier Company Name using:

`<Text text="{Suppliers/CompanyName}"/>`

However, I can see why this wouldn't work but I cannot figure out how to get it to work.

Thanks for your help.

Please see what I have tried below:

```
<Table 
    id="table" 
    width="auto" 
    class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" 
    items="{
        path: '/Products',
        sorter: {
            path: 'ProductName',
            descending: false
        }
    }" 
    noDataText="{worklistView>/tableNoDataText}"
    busyIndicatorDelay="{worklistView>/tableBusyDelay}"
    growing="true"
    growingScrollToLoad="true"
    updateFinished="onUpdateFinished">

    <!--    parameters:{expand : 'Category'}, -->
    <headerToolbar>
        <Toolbar id="toolbar">
            <Title id="tableHeader" text="{worklistView>/worklistTableTitle}" />
            <ToolbarSpacer />
            <SearchField id="searchField" tooltip="{i18n>worklistSearchTooltip}" search="onSearch" width="auto" />
        </Toolbar>
    </headerToolbar>
    <columns>
        <Column id="nameColumn">
            <Text text="{i18n>tableNameColumnTitle}" id="nameColumnTitle" />
        </Column>
        <Column id="unitNumberColumn" hAlign="End">
            <Text text="{i18n>tableUnitNumberColumnTitle}" id="unitNumberColumnTitle" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="SupplierName" id="SupplierName" />
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem type="Navigation" press="onPress">
            <cells>
                <ObjectIdentifier title="{ProductName}" />
                <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'UnitPrice', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }" />
                <Text text="{Suppliers/CompanyName}" />
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

Product:

```
<EntityType Name="Product">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ProductID" />
    </Key>
    <Property xmlns:p6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" Name="ProductID" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" p6:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
    <Property Name="ProductName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
    <Property Name="SupplierID" Type="Edm.Int32" />
    <Property Name="CategoryID" Type="Edm.Int32" />
    <Property Name="QuantityPerUnit" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
    <Property Name="UnitPrice" Type="Edm.Decimal" Precision="19" Scale="4" />
    <Property Name="UnitsInStock" Type="Edm.Int16" />
    <Property Name="UnitsOnOrder" Type="Edm.Int16" />
    <Property Name="ReorderLevel" Type="Edm.Int16" />
    <Property Name="Discontinued" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false" />
    <NavigationProperty Name="Category" Relationship="NorthwindModel.FK_Products_Categories" ToRole="Categories" FromRole="Products" />
    <NavigationProperty Name="Order_Details" Relationship="NorthwindModel.FK_Order_Details_Products" ToRole="Order_Details" FromRole="Products" />
    <NavigationProperty Name="Supplier" Relationship="NorthwindModel.FK_Products_Suppliers" ToRole="Suppliers" FromRole="Products" />
</EntityType>
```

Supplier:

```
<EntityType Name="Supplier">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="SupplierID" />
    </Key>
    <Property xmlns:p6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" Name="SupplierID" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" p6:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
    <Property Name="CompanyName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
    <Property Name="ContactName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="30" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
    <Property Name="ContactTitle" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="30" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
    <Property Name="Address" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="60" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
    <Property Name="City" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="15" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
    <Property Name="Region" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="15" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
    <Property Name="PostalCode" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="10" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
    <Property Name="Country" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="15" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
    <Property Name="Phone" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="24" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
    <Property Name="Fax" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="24" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
    <Property Name="HomePage" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="Max" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
    <NavigationProperty Name="Products" Relationship="NorthwindModel.FK_Products_Suppliers" ToRole="Products" FromRole="Suppliers" />
</EntityType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is nothing wrong with expanding the complete `Supplier` entity. It shouldn't make a huge difference on the size/loading time of the response.

In fact, if you open the *Chrome Dev Tools* and track the time of your current request and my solution below, both times will be very similar (it's even faster without a select)

[image]

[image]

It surely makes a difference when you compare the size of the response.

- Without the $select, you get `Content-Length:2547`
- With $select, you get `Content-Length:836` (so only a third)

Notice that the unit is **Bytes**! So both requests are still very tiny.

---

But to answer your question: In theory, the `$select` operator in combination with a nested URL should help you.

However, keep in mind that nested URLs where added in OData v4.

This is the URL that gives you your desired result

http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?$select=ProductName,UnitPrice&$expand=Supplier($select=CompanyName)

You can see that I applied a `$select` on the main entity (Products). If you wanted all properties from the `Products`, but only the `CompanyName` of the `Suppliers`, simply change the parent-level `$select` to `$select=*`

http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?$select=*&$expand=Supplier($select=CompanyName)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would I include a nested URL into my XML code (i.e. into my table rows).

Comment: It's a URL parameter so I'd try using the parameter `parameter` of the `items` aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

**1. Set parameters:**

```
 items="{
   path: '/Products',
   parameters:{expand : 'Supplier'}
   sorter: {
            path: 'ProductName',
            descending: false
           }
 }"
```

**2. Bind the Navigation property to get properties**

```
<Text text="{Supplier/CompanyName}"/>
```

> Notice that you had Suppliers which is wrong, because `Supplier` is
>   the navigational property

PS: It was very detailed & useful insight from [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1083921/marc)